# How to display category's items?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display items of each category I have. I use smarty templates. So I get categories like this:

```
{foreach $news as $article}
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{$article["name"]}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            "Here I need to display Items that have FOREIGN KEY 'category_id'" 
        </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Whether I should get a category's ID and how then to display it?
[It's a category list with ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzYQB.png)

I want to improve my question - here some links to my [Controller](http://joxi.net/EA44WR8CezdlAb). I've tried to put more links, but incase of low reputation I couldn't.  Please try to see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$lists = '';
$query = "your query example" - mysqli_query($conn,"select * from article"); 
if(!$mysqli_num_rows<0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row["category_id"];
    $name = $row["name"];

    $lists .= '<div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">'.$name.'</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            "Here I need to display Items that have FOREIGN KEY '.$id.'" 
        </div>
    </div>';
}

    echo $lists;
}


?>
```